# Create two separate Alternate for media library picker field in Detail and summary mode of a custom content type

Tags: orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. I have created a custom content type name "Animal" that has a MediaLibraryPicker field. And I have created a projection to show a list of Animals. In this list I want to show `Parts_Image_Summary` and in Animal Detail mode I want to show `Parts_Image_Detail`.
For this Purpose I created an Alternate `Fields.MediaLibraryPicker-Animal.cshtml` and Changed its Code from

```
@Display(BuildDisplay(content, "Summary"))
```

to

```
@Display(BuildDisplay(content, "Detail"))
```

Problem is this alternate effects both Animal Detail mode and Animal Summary mode which I just need this alternate for Animal detail Mode.

`Shape tracer` doesn't show any alternate name that fits my need.
I tried to change the alternate file name to `Fields.MediaLibraryPicker-Animal-Detail.cshtml` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orchard has a lot of field alternates, but these alternates did not include this one, but you can add any new alternate simply by implementing `IShapeTableProvider` interface as following:

```cs
public class Shapes : IShapeTableProvider {
    public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder) {
        builder.Describe("Fields_MediaLibraryPicker")
           .OnDisplaying(displaying => {
               ContentItem contentItem = displaying.Shape.ContentItem as ContentItem;

               if (contentItem == null) {
                   return;
               }

               // [ShapeType]__[ContentType]__[DisplayType] e.g. Fields.MediaLibraryPicker-Animal-Detail
               displaying.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add(EncodeAlternateElement(
                   displaying.ShapeMetadata.Type + "__" +
                   contentItem.ContentType + "__" +
                   displaying.ShapeMetadata.DisplayType));
           });
    }

    private string EncodeAlternateElement(string alternateElement) {
        return alternateElement.Replace("-", "__").Replace(".", "_").Replace(" ", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it helped alot